# Microsecond do not work in Python logger format

Tags: python, logging, time, format, python-logging

For some reason my Python logger does not want to recognize microseconds format.

```
import logging, io

stream = io.StringIO()
logger = logging.getLogger("TestLogger")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.propagate = False
log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
log_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
logger.addHandler(log_handler)

logger.info("This is test info log")
print(stream.getvalue())
```

It returns:

```
2023-01-06 18:52:34.%f UTC - TestLogger - INFO - This is test info log
```

Why are microseconds missing?

**Update**

I am running
Python 3.10.4
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:    11
Codename:   bullseye

Comment: On my system (Python 3.9.7) the sample program fails with error "Value Error: Invalid format string". If I remove the ".%f" from the format string the program runs without complain (but of course prints only the whole seconds value, no fractional part)

Comment: Now that you mention it I cannot seem to find any definitive documentation that claims that microsecond resolution is available for python logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the [`formatTime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72263f2a20002ceff443e3a231c713f2e14fe3fe/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L606) method uses [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) to format the current `time.time()`, but since [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) has no information about `milliseconds` and `microseconds` the formatter ignores the `%f`.

Also, note that the `LogRecord` calculates the milliseconds separately and stores them in another variable named [`msecs`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72263f2a20002ceff443e3a231c713f2e14fe3fe/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L337)

To get what you're looking for we need a custom version of the `Formatter` class that uses a different converter than [`time.localtime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/72263f2a20002ceff443e3a231c713f2e14fe3fe/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L574) and is able to interpret the microseconds:

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def formatTime(self, record, datefmt=None):
        if not datefmt:
            return super().formatTime(record, datefmt=datefmt)

        return datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().strftime(datefmt)


...
log_format = MyFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")
...
```

Should output:

`2023-01-06 17:47:54.828521 EST - TestLogger - INFO - This is test info log`

Answer (score 2):

I found that the answer given by Ashwini Chaudhary to not be applicable for me and found a slightly simpler solution in creating a function with the formatting as done with `datetime` and changing the value of the `logging.Formatter.formatTime` method to this instead i.e.:

```
def _formatTime(self, record,  datefmt: str = None) -> str:
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(record.created).astimezone().strftime(datefmt)

log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z")

logging.Formatter.formatTime = _formatTime
```

And then generating your logger as normal